# Checking if a message was sent from a DM channel type not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using Discord.js v12 and trying to check if a message was sent from a DM but it doesn't work for me, I have tried this method:

```
  if (msg.channel.type === 'dm')
```

This was working fine couple months ago but it doesn't work anymore. When i try `console.log(msg.channel.type)` it only returns text and doesn't return dm when the bot gets an DM and I can't find any solutions for this.

Comment: Oh, do you mean `console.log(msg.channel.type)` the string `"text"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't updated your discord.js version and you're still using v12?

Channel types in v13 are now uppercase and align with Discord's naming conventions. See below the changes:

| channel type | v12 | v13 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DM channel | `dm` | `DM` |
| group DM channel | N/A | `GROUP_DM` |
| guild text channel | `text` | `GUILD_TEXT` |
| guild text channel's public thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD` |
| guild text channel's private thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_PRIVATE_THREAD` |
| guild voice channel | `voice` | `GUILD_VOICE` |
| guild stage voice channel | N/A | `GUILD_STAGE_VOICE` |
| guild category channel | `category` | `GUILD_CATEGORY` |
| guild news channel | `news` | `GUILD_NEWS` |
| guild news channel's public thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_NEWS_THREAD` |
| guild store channel | `store` | `GUILD_STORE` |
| generic channel of unknown type | `unknown` | `UNKNOWN` |

It means, that if you want to check if the `channel`'s `type` is DM, you need to use:

```js
if (msg.channel.type === 'DM')
```

There are some changes in v14 too. You can [use the `ChannelType` enums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027955/6126373):

```js
const { ChannelType, Client } = require('discord.js');
// ..
if (message.channel.type === ChannelType.DM)
```