# Discord.js doesn't collect DM from user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a bot to verify members on a special guild.
They need to send `"verify"` into a specific channel, then they have to answer several questions. However, the collector doesn't seem to work properly. Nothing shows in console.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if(message.author.id === botId) return;

    if(message.channel.type != "dm") {
        if(message.channelId == verifyChannelId && message.content == "verify") {
            let appChannel = (await message.author.send('Hello, I\'m gonna asking you a few questions..')).channel;

            appChannel.send('Are you on european server? (Yes/No)');
        
            const filter = m => (appChannel.type === "dm");
            const collector = appChannel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
        
            collector.on('collect', m => {
                console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`);
            });
        
            collector.on('end', collected => {
                console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
            });

            message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
        } else {
            message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a message was sent from a DM not working. (Discord.js v12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002410/checking-if-a-message-was-sent-from-a-dm-not-working-discord-js-v12)

Comment: @MrMythical still not sadly

Comment: Is the `DIRECT_MESSAGES` intent present in your `<Client>` instantiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors with this. First, you're using v13 of discord.js and as MrMythical mentioned in their comment, [channel types are now uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003784/6126373), so checking `if(message.channel.type != "dm")` won't do much as it will always return `true`. Checking if `(appChannel.type === "dm")` won't work either as it will always returns `false`. And I'm not even sure why you'd check if the `appChannel`'s type is `DM` anyway, it can't be anything else. Your `filter` should probably check if the answer is `yes` or `no`.

Another error is that you haven't enabled the [`DIRECT_MESSAGES` intents](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS). Without it, your `createMessageCollector` won't work in DM channels. Check out the working code below:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
  ],
});

// ...

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  // it could be if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.author.id === botId) return;
  if (message.channel.type === 'DM') return;
  if (message.channelId !== verifyChannelId) return;

  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'verify') {
    let sentMessage = await message.author.send(
      "Hello, I'm gonna asking you a few questions..",
    );
    let dmChannel = sentMessage.channel;

    dmChannel.send('Are you on a European server? (Yes/No)');

    const filter = (m) => ['yes', 'no'].includes(m.content.toLowerCase());
    const collector = dmChannel.createMessageCollector({
      filter,
      // max: 1,
      time: 15000,
    });

    collector.on('collect', (m) => {
      console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`);
    });

    collector.on('end', (collected) => {
      console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
    });
  }

  // delete the message even if it wasn't "verify"
  message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
});
```