# Discord - conversation in DM with bot

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I found a way where a bot send me DM when I write !whitelist in my server but when I want to talk with the bot in DM it's not working

```
client.on("message", async message => {
        if (message.content === "!whitelist") {
            message.guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => {
                if (member.roles.cache.has(staffID)) {
                    member.send(`Hey ! Congratulation you are whitelisted ! `);
    if (message.content === "!speak")
{
member.send(`Hi how are you ?`);
}
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: Do you have the `DIRECT_MESSAGES` intents enabled?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros actually when I run this I get the DM but when I want to keep talk with bot in DM it's not working

Comment: Ah, I see. But `if (message.content === "!speak")` would never be true if you're in the block `if (message.content === "!whitelist")`. It can't be both. Not sure what you want, but if you want collecting messages, you could get some idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70065784/6126373

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting a reply from the user in dm's

If that's the case you'll have to use a `collector` or `awaitMessages`

Your code is also in djs v12; I recommend you to update to djs v13 for support and more features

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.content === "!whitelist") {
        message.guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => {
            if (member.roles.cache.has(staffID)) {
                member.send(`Hey ! Congratulation you are whitelisted ! `).then(msg => {
                    const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                    msg.channel.awaitMessages({filter: filter1, time: 5 * 12000, max: 1}).then(messages =>{
                        let msg1 = messages.first().content
                        if(msg1 === "!speak"){
                            member.send('Hi how are you?')
                        }
                    })
                })
        
            }
        })
    }
})
```