# Discord.js issue at finding channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a verify command but I keep getting stuck on the bot saying "Please Enter A Valid Channel!" even with a valid channel name.

```
 let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() ||
 message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]) ||
 message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() ===
 args[0].toLocaleLowerCase());
         if (!channel || channel.type !== 'text') return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Valid Channel!**");
```

Example:
[Discord Example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJPQd.png)

Don't mind the role mention. It's for a role to be given when reacting

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In discord.js v13 channels types have changed:

| channel type | v12 | v13 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DM channel | `dm` | `DM` |
| group DM channel | N/A | `GROUP_DM` |
| guild text channel | `text` | `GUILD_TEXT` |
| guild text channel's public thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD` |
| guild text channel's private thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_PRIVATE_THREAD` |
| guild voice channel | `voice` | `GUILD_VOICE` |
| guild stage voice channel | N/A | `GUILD_STAGE_VOICE` |
| guild category channel | `category` | `GUILD_CATEGORY` |
| guild news channel | `news` | `GUILD_NEWS` |
| guild news channel's public thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_NEWS_THREAD` |
| guild store channel | `store` | `GUILD_STORE` |
| generic channel of unknown type | `unknown` | `UNKNOWN` |

This table was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002410/checking-if-a-message-was-sent-from-a-dm-not-working-discord-js-v12/70003784#70003784) made by [@Zsolt Meszaros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6126373/zsolt-meszaros)

Change your code to this:

```js
if (!channel || channel.type !== "GUILD_TEXT") return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Valid Channel!**")
```