# Discord JS - Counting voice and text channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Trying to make a counter for text and voice channels. So it should exclude the amoount of categories.

```js
module.exports = async (client) => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('912706237806829598');

  setInterval(async () => {
    const channelCount = (await guild.channels.fetch()).filter(
      (channel) => channel.type !== 'category'
    ).size;
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('960790479925039124');
    channel.setName(`╭・Channels: ${channelCount.toLocaleString()}`);
    console.log('Updating Channel Count');
    console.log(channelCount);
  }, 600000);
};
```

This gives me 183 which is wrong. The number I want to achieve is 155. I have 28 categories, so 183 makes sense if the categories aren't filtered. Filtering the categories has been a bigger struggle that I anticipated.

I have also tried to filter on the cache. `guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type !== 'category').size;` but it results in the same way (183). So the filtering isn't working as intended.

Comment: What's your discord.js version? v13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using discord.js v13+, [channel types are now uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003784/6126373) and align with Discord's naming conventions. See below the changes:

| channel type | v12 | v13 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DM channel | `dm` | `DM` |
| group DM channel | N/A | `GROUP_DM` |
| guild text channel | `text` | `GUILD_TEXT` |
| guild text channel's public thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD` |
| guild text channel's private thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_PRIVATE_THREAD` |
| guild voice channel | `voice` | `GUILD_VOICE` |
| guild stage voice channel | N/A | `GUILD_STAGE_VOICE` |
| guild category channel | `category` | `GUILD_CATEGORY` |
| guild news channel | `news` | `GUILD_NEWS` |
| guild news channel's public thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_NEWS_THREAD` |
| guild store channel | `store` | `GUILD_STORE` |
| generic channel of unknown type | `unknown` | `UNKNOWN` |

As you can see, `category` is now `GUILD_CATEGORY`. It means, your filter (`channel.type !== 'category'`) won't match anything, as there is no `category` type anymore. To fix this, you can use the following:

```js
const channelCount = (await guild.channels.fetch()).filter(
  (channel) => channel.type !== 'GUILD_CATEGORY'
).size;
```