# Nothing happens when the command is run

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When I run the '!hi' command, nothing happens. There is no console output or error in the terminal as well. I checked a lot of answers on the Internet, but none of them worked. This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES'] })

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is now online!')
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    if (message.channel.type !== 'text') return
    let prefix = '!'
    let MessageArray = message.content.split(' ')
    let cmd = MessageArray[0]
    let args = MessageArray.slice(1)

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return

    if (cmd == 'hello') {
        message.channel.send('hello')
    }
})

client.login(`*******************************************`)
```

Comment: It's because `message.channel.type` will never be `text`. Is it meant to be `GUILD_TEXT`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a message was sent from a DM not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002410/checking-if-a-message-was-sent-from-a-dm-not-working)

Comment: no i still don't understand

Comment: What part is confusing? `message.channel.type` will never be `text`, so you will always `return` after that `if` statement. You need to replace `text` with `GUILD_TEXT`.

Comment: I change text to GUILD_TEXT and it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, because you don't remove the `prefix` from `cmd`. It should be `let cmd =  MessageArray[0].slice(prefix.length)`.

Comment: Yeah, no idea what that is as there is no `.first()` method in your current code. Check what's before `.first()`, that's `undefined`.

Comment: i add some new code https://gyazo.com/4c5244fcca1e56c180717b2113549d63
and here i have the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first')"

Comment: It's a typo, `message.mentions.member.first()` needs to be `message.mentions.members.first()`. You missed an 's' in the `members`

Comment: sorry again but i have a new error :( 
    ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Miryk\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Comment: here is my code: index.js: https://gyazo.com/96f1c88f333a72fc53247a8cfd96740d
hello.js: https://gyazo.com/600d1a676caf3d4f785e0969dcdc290a

Comment: Again it's a typo. When you declared `discord` you did so with a small 'd', but in your second line you are using it as `Discord` with a capital 'D'

Comment: ok i change this now i have this error: https://gyazo.com/c07132438006a314a6033d442d7c0cac

Comment: Import `Intents` from `discord.js` then in the line where you declare the client use this instead => `const client = new discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] })`

Comment: New errors should be posted as new questions.

Answer (score -2):

Your command dont work because **cmd** is equal to "!hello" instead of "hello",
to fix it:

`let cmd = MessageArray[0].substring(1)`

The **substring** function is for that