# Discord TypeError: message.channel.isText is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've a Discord bot where I'm checking if a channel is a text channel. The following code worked until today, but now it throws an error.

```
if (message.channel.isText()) { ... }
```

Error:

```
  if (message.channel.isText())
                      ^
TypeError: message.channel.isText is not a function
```

I also tried it with `message.channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT'` but it always returns `false`, even if the channel is a text channel.

Answer (score 3):

In discordjs v14, `channel#isText()`, `channel#isVoice()`, `channel#isDM()`, etc. are not available any more. You should use the [`ChannelType` enums](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ChannelType) instead.

If you want to check if a channel is a [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.0.1/class/TextChannel), you can use the following:

```js
const { ChannelType, Client } = require('discord.js');
// ..
if (message.channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText)
```

Also, `channel.type` is no longer a string but a number. For example, `channel.type` for a `TextChannel` returns `0`, that's why `channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT'` no longer works for you.

Here is a list of channel types in v14:

| channel type | v12 | v13 | v14 | v14 `type()` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| guild text channel | `text` | `GUILD_TEXT` | `GuildText` | `0` |
| DM channel | `dm` | `DM` | `DM` | `1` |
| guild voice channel | `voice` | `GUILD_VOICE` | `GuildVoice` | `2` |
| group DM channel | N/A | `GROUP_DM` | `GroupDM` | `3` |
| guild category channel | `category` | `GUILD_CATEGORY` | `GuildCategory` | `4` |
| guild news channel | `news` | `GUILD_NEWS` | `GuildNews` | `5` |
| guild news channel's public thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_NEWS_THREAD` | `GuildNewsThread` | `10` |
| guild text channel's public thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD` | `GuildPublicThread` | `11` |
| guild text channel's private thread channel | N/A | `GUILD_PRIVATE_THREAD` | `GuildPrivateThread` | `12` |
| guild stage voice channel | N/A | `GUILD_STAGE_VOICE` | `GuildStageVoice` | `13` |
| guild store channel | `store` | `GUILD_STORE` | N/A | N/A |
| generic channel of unknown type | `unknown` | `UNKNOWN` | N/A | N/A |

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js’ `BaseChannel` class doesn’t have an `isText()` method, at least not according to its latest API docs.

Is it possible you meant to use [`isTextBased()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseChannel?scrollTo=isTextBased) method instead?

```
if (message.channel.isTextBased()) { /* … */ }
```