# Discord chatbot not responding to Dms for discord.js v14.7

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi }= require('openai');
const configuration = new Configuration( {
    organization: process.env.ORG_API,
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_BOT,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi (configuration);

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ],
})
client.login(process.env.D_API);

let conversation = "Steak is discord chatbot, straight male and is mostly friendly till someone tries to insult him. \nUser : Crack a misogenist joke. \nSteak : how many feminists does it take to change a light bulb. \nUser : How many? \nSteak : 0 because they can't change anything."
client.on('messageCreate', async function(message){
  try {
      console.log(`Received message of type: ${message.channel.type}`);

      if (message.author.bot) return; // ignore messages from other bots

      // Append the message to the conversation variable
      conversation += `\n${message.author.username}: ${message.content}\nSteak:`;

      // Send a request to the OpenAI API to generate a response
      const response = await openai.createCompletion({
          model: "davinci",
          prompt: conversation,
          temperature: 0.86,
          max_tokens: 1001,
          stop: ["Steak:", "\nuser :", `${message.author.username}:`, "\n\n"],
      });

      conversation += response.data.choices[0].text;
      console.log(`${message.content}`);
      message.reply(`${response.data.choices[0].text}`);
      return;
  } catch(err){
      console.log(err);
  }
});

client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
    try {
        console.log(`Received message in DM: ${message.content}`);

        if (message.author.bot) return; // ignore messages from other bots

        // Append the message to the conversation variable
        conversation += `\n${message.author.username}: ${message.content}\nSteak:`;

        // Send a request to the OpenAI API to generate a response
        const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "davinci",
            prompt: conversation,
            temperature: 0.86,
            max_tokens: 1001,
            stop: ["Steak:", "\nuser :", `${message.author.username}:`, "\n\n"],
        });

        conversation += response.data.choices[0].text;
        console.log(`${message.content}`);
        message.author.send(`${response.data.choices[0].text}`);
        return;
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
  }
});



client.on('ready', () => { 
  console.log('bot is ready'); 
});

console.log ("Steak is Online on Discord")
```

The bot is responding only to messages sent to guild please tell me how to make it to reply to messages send in dm. It is basicall a discord.js bot and I think it that all the required intends please tell what should I do to make it reply to dms also, currently it is working correctly with the messages sent on guild.

I wanted it to respond in the same way to dms the way it is responding to messages in guild please tell what corrections have to be made

Comment: Why do you have both `messageCreate` and `message` events?

Comment: initially I only created `messageCreate` to listen to any message but later on when it was not working for DMs I thought of creating another one for DMs but still dosen't work for Dms

Comment: Anyway, you can use [`if (message.channel.type === Discord.ChannelType.DM)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027955/6126373) in discord.js v14. And there is no `message` event, only `messageCreate` now.

Comment: but it is working fine with message also

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: v14 prolly don't know the exact version
dorry my bad it is using `messageCreate` only